# Proving that if $A$ is a $8\times 8$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ and $A^3=A$, then $A$ is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

> If $A$ is a $8\times 8$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ and $A^3=A$ then prove that $A$ is diagonalizable.

I have got that the minimal polynomial of $A$ may be $x^3-x$ or $x$ or $x(x+1)$ or $x(x-1)$ in the 2nd case it is not possible in the 3rd and 4th cases the matrix will be the identity matrix or identity matrix multiplied by a scalar!

But I cannot reach any further.

Comment: I have got that the minimal polynomial of A may be x^3-x or x or x(x+1) or x(x-1) in the 2nd case it is not possible in the 3rd and 4th cases the matrix will be the identity matrix or identity matrix multiplied by a scalar!!But I can't reach any further

Comment: Sir I don't know how to write codes for that title what you have written!!And I observe you are very keen to search my mistakes other than solving my problem!! Thanking You I won't post anything else in this site

Comment: *"Sir I don't know how to write codes for that title what you have written"*: Here is a [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I have removed my close vote and my downvote. $A$ is annihilated by $X^3-X$, a polynomial with simple roots. It is therefore diagonalizable. But I don't know if you have the machinery at hand to prove this lemma (see [this](http://math.kangwon.ac.kr/~yhpark/webla/lin-alg/node8.html) or lookup "kernel decomposition theorem" ).

Comment: *"And I observe you are very keen to search my mistakes other than solving my problem"*: This is not the reason we ask for your attempts on the problem. One of the reasons (among [many others](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960)) is because you'll likely receive answers better suited to your specific needs.

Comment: I got it!!Thank You!!I'll remember how to post in this site!!

Comment: It is easily seen that 0,1,-1 is the eigen values of A.Now x^3 -x is the minimal polynomial satisfied by those eigen values.Therefore the minimal polynomial of A is x^3-x and this minimal polynomial can be written as the linear factors of the eigenvalues that is x^3-x=x(x+1)(x-1) therefore it is diagonizabile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any $v$, since $A(A-I)(A+I)v=0$, you get that:

1. $v_{1}=(A^2+A)v$ is either zero or an eigenvector for eigenvalue $1$.
2. $v_{-1}=(A^2-A)v$ is either zero or an eigenvector for eigenvalue $-1$.
3. $v_0=(A^2-I)v$ is either zero or an eigenvector for eigenvalue $0$.

Now, note that:

$$v=\frac{1}{2}v_1+\frac{1}{2}v_{-1}-v_0$$

Why does this show that $A$ is diagonalizable?

---

In general, if $p(A)=0$ for some $p(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots (x-a_k)$ for distinct $a_i$ (thus, not repeat roots) then $A$ can be diagonalized.

Specifically, if we define $p_i(x)=\prod_{j\neq i} (x-a_j)$ then we get that:

$$1=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{p_i(a_i)}p_i(x)$$

So if $v_i=p_i(A)v$ then $v_i$ is an eigenvector for eigenvalue $a_i$ and:

$$v = \sum \frac{1}{p_i(a_i)} v_i$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the matrix $A$ is a zero of the polynomial $$p(x) = x^3 - x = x (x-1)(x+1)$$, the minimal polynomial of $A$ has to divide the polynomial $p$, but this means that $m$ is some combinations of the factors $x$, $(x-1)$, and $(x+1)$, but this implies that $A$ is diagonalisable.

QED.