# How to prove that if $f^3 = f$, $f$ is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Prove that

> Let $V$ be a finite dim. vector space over a field of characteristic zero, and $f: V \to V$ be a linear
>   map.Then if $$f^3 = f,$$ then $f$ is diagonalizable.

Since $f$ is zero of the polynomial $$p(x) = x^3 - x$$
the minimal polynomial $m_f$ should divide $p$, hence $m_f$ can be the following polynomials only:
$$m(x) = (x-1) \\ = x \\ = x+ 1 \\ =x^2 - x \\ = x^2 + x \\ = x^2 - 1 \\ =x(x-1)(x+1) $$

**But, I couldn't show that if $m$ is either of the followings $ x^2 + x $ & $ x^2 - 1  $ & $ x(x-1)(x+1) $, it should be diagonalizable.**
**So for these 3 cases how can we prove that $f$ should be diagonalizable ?**

Comment: The proof is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2511311/proving-that-if-a-is-a-8-times-8-matrix-over-mathbbr-and-a3-a-then?rq=1). It works for all sizes.

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $f$ divides $p(x)=x^3-x$. If the minimal polynomial is a product of distinct linear factors it is diagonalizable. (I assume this result has already been seen?)

Comment: Striclty, you need to mention the field. It is false in characteristic two (and only there).

Comment: @quid The field is characteristic zero.

Answer (score 1):

Since the matrix $f$ is a zero of the polynomial $$p(x) = x^3 - x = x (x-1)(x+1),$$ the minimal polynomial of $f$ has to divide the polynomial $p$, but this means that $m$ is some combinations of the factors $x$, $(x-1)$, and $(x+1)$ with each having the multiplicity 1, but this implies that $f$ is diagonalisable.

QED.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $x^3-x$ aplits as a product of *distinct* linear factors, hence the minimal polynomial of $f$, which is a divisor of $x^3-x$, is  a product of *distinct* linear factors too. This is the criterion for a linear map to be diagonalisable.

Comment: How this is different from my answer ?